# Advantage OLE DB Provider hangs on Windows 7 system

Tags: advantage-database-server

I have a program written in VFP v9 SP2 working for years. Recently got a new box with Windows 7 on it and have to re-install all my tools. Advantage OLE DB provider was one of them.  When I’ve tried to run my trusted program, it hangs on a first call to OLE DB Provider
The (relevant) code is:

```
loConn = createobject("ADODB.Connection")
 …
*cDD has beendefined previously and points to the Data Dictionary file  

loConn.ConnectionString = 'Provider=Advantage OLE DB Provider; Data Source='+cDD+';  
  ServerType=ADS_LOCAL_SERVER|ADS_REMOTE_SERVER; User ID=user;Password=password'

loConn.open()   && Hangs right here! (Not responding for minutes)
```

After installation I’ve checked folder where provider installed, but all dlls are in place along with another files… Any ideas? Where to look?

Answer (score 1):

OleDB is not supported on windows 7 64 bits. Microsoft doesn't intend to migrate it to new 64 bits operating systems.